# how to get the private key for an used address ?

Tags: address, private-key, address-generation, private-key-export, recover-private-key

I have used an address generated by Exodus wallet. whats happened is that my bitcoin confirmed but didn't receive any thing on Exodus wallet. I want now to import private key in another wallet. but when I export private key in Exodus wallet so there is no private key for the address I have used. the private keys only for new generated adresses. any one have got through such thing ?? any one have an idea how to get private key for used address ? it looks like that I had to export private key for the address before I use it. because it looks like that the private key disappear with the address after using ? is that true ? any explanation ?

Comment: Have you tried the [export Private Keys feature](http://support.exodus.io/article/77-does-exodus-have-advanced-export-options)? Is explicitly stated "The Export Private Keys feature will export all of your private keys"

Comment: I tried but this is my point the address doesn't exist so the private key also. private keys there are only for the new generated addresses. you know after I used the address to receive my bitcoin, the wallet generated a new address, this address I can export its private key, but not the one I used. the wallet does not show me the address I used or its transaction or its private key. its just disappear and new addresses become generated.

Comment: You can try to [import your Exodus 12-word phrase into Electrum](http://support.exodus.io/article/159-import-your-bitcoin-wallet-into-electrum). All private keys derived from your 12-word phrase and related transactions should show up. If you have used more than 20 addresses, you will need to increase something called the gap_limit in Electrum to show beyond the first 20 public addresses.

Comment: I am confused now. I import it into electrum but can't see the transaction also.

Comment: this is what I did.. I tok the address from Exodus and I used it into cex.io I receive confirmation from cex.io and it confirmed in the blockchain but didn't receive any thing in Exodus and there is no private key or something related to this transaction in Exodus. is there any way to know that this address belong to Exodus wallet, because I am confused now.

Comment: Can you clarify, which wallet and address did you sent from, and to which wallet and address. It sounds to me like you imported an external private key into Exodus from somewhere else.

Comment: I use CEX.IO. I wanted to transfer 0.009bitcoin that I bought in CEX.IO to Exodus wallet. and I had did it right I received confirmation from CEX.IO and the transaction became confirmed in blockchain, but I didn't receive it in Exodus wallet. this is the first transaction I did it when I download Exodus wallet. in Exodus there is no password or 12-word phrase yet. if I go to backup button, it telling me that I need to make first deposit to create backup. I exported the addresses and private keys, but the address I used is not there. there is a new address.

Comment: all what I have now the address I used and confirmation from CEX.IO that I send my bitcoin to this address.

Comment: Something is confusing here. I mean if you didn't receive the first deposit from Cex.io to Exodus deposit address, how were you able to unlock the 12-word passphrase?

Comment: yes I am sorry about that. its my mistake there is no 12-wrod phrase. that one was for Daedalus wallet and I thought its for Exodus.

Comment: Isn't the minimum BTC withdrawal 0.01BTC on Cex.io? Do you have a transaction id?

Comment: yes but they tok some fees so the 0.01 become 0.009

Comment: Withdrawal details: 
Instrument: Crypto 
Requested amount: BTC 0.01000000 
Commission: BTC 0.00100000 
Total to be sent: BTC 0.00900000

Comment: I think this is the transaction id: e361f1a392a003a7b210f434656e64318b94a4195a03fe5128e0d8884c82b4ec

Comment: and this is the address: 1UyoYU6kTD7uuZK6vXEpNiVNN66X9WNj6

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that 1UyoYU6kTD7uuZK6vXEpNiVNN66X9WNj6 was your Exodus deposit address, and now it has disappeared even using the latest version. Sounds like a buggy wallet to me. From this point on only [Exodus support will be able to help you](http://support.exodus.io/article/93-how-can-i-contact-exodus). There is actually one last thing you can do, [Export ->XPub](http://support.exodus.io/article/112-how-to-export-your-bitcoin-xpub-key) then go to blockchain.info/xpub/'add your XPub key here' without the single quotes. This will list every transactions of your wallet.

Comment: I also assume that you didn't touch the folder C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Exodus

Comment: I tried this now. 0 transaction. I dont understand I download the app from there official site. anyway I am trying to contact with them. but thank you so much for informations it was helpful anyway.